# Exact word based web scraping of newspaper articles in python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all the newspaper articles which contain key word 'rain' in it. Below is the code given. The problem I encounter is that the result returns those links which has the word 'rain' embedded in it, like 'train', 'brain', 'training'. How can I avoid this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import numpy as np
import requests
import re
import os
data=[]
Y=np.arange(1,13,1)
Z=np.arange(1,32,1)
for j in Y:
           for k in Z:
                      url = f'https://www.thehindu.com/archive/print/2018/{j}/{k}/'
                      r = requests.get(url)
                      soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
                      for a in soup.findAll('a', string=re.compile('rain',re.IGNORECASE)):
                                                                                P = a['href']
                                                                                data.append([P])
```

Comment: Look up how to handle word boundaries in regex.

Comment: @Prune good catch

Comment: `soup.findAll('a', string=re.compile(r'(?=.*\brain\b)',re.IGNORECASE))`

Comment: Thank you  chitown88